# Linear Equations in Primes, Green Tao

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, ergodic-theory

Ben Green and Terence Tao, Linear Equations in Prime, Page 1764 and 1765. Are the products in Examples 5, 6, 7, 8 taken over the set of natural numbers or the set of prime numbers? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products in Examples $5$, $6$, $7$ and $8$ are all taken over the set of primes, not of all of the natural numbers.

Note each example talks about primes, e.g., Example $5$ starts with "The number of $4$-tuples of primes $p_1 \lt p_2 \lt p_3 \lt p_4 \le N \ldots$". Also, the use of the symbol $p$, although it obviously doesn't involve primes in all situations, is nonetheless another indication here they are only dealing with primes. In addition, in Example $7$, the first product has $p \mid N^3 - N$ and the second product has $p \not\mid N^3 - N$, with this once again indicating the products are over the primes, with this example splitting between those which divide $N^3 - N$ and those which don't. Finally, and most conclusively, the results they provide are only true if the products are over the primes.

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask you a simple question : what do they mean by $o(1)$ ?

Comment: And $o_k(1)$ in their article?

Comment: @Neilhawking The $o$ in $o(1)$ is "little-o", with details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), [here](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Little-o_notation) & [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html). In particular, if say the variable is $N$, so $f(N) = o(1)$ replaces the symbol, then $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{f(N)}{1} = 0$. In other words, the value becomes arbitrarily small. Near the end of Ex. #$5$, you have $\left(c + o(1)\right)\frac{N^2}{\log^4 N}$, with this meaning the coefficient $c + o(1) \to c \text{ as } N \to \infty$.

Comment: @Neilhawking As for $o_k(1)$, it seems to be used there to mean that the variable is $k$. For example, in Ex. #$8$, the first expression uses $k$ and $N$, so $o_k(1)$ is used to make sure it's clear that $f(k) = o_k(1)$ so $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(k)}{1} = 0$, rather than it going to $0$ as $N \to \infty$ instead.